# How to build a chatbot using .NET Core and dialogflow?

Tags: asp.net-core, dialogflow-es

I'm building my own MVC web application using .NET Core and I want to add a chatbot application in my website.

In my point of view, after building an agent in dialogflow, and then I should can use webhook to let my C# application to connect to the agent which already exists and push request to it and get response from the agent.

How can I connect .NET Core client to dialogflow agent which already exists or may be some reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fairly easy. Follow the instructions below :

1. Install Nuget package Google.Apis.Dialogflow.v2 and its dependencies.
2. Create the GCP credentials access key. Save the JSON to your local machine.
3. Connect to GCP by setting-up the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. Refer the following code :
   `System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", _CredentialsPath)` :
4. Use following like code to

   Public Function GetResponseTo(whatUserSays As String) As String

   ```
       Dim textInput As New TextInput, queryInput As New QueryInput

       textInput.Text = whatUserSays
       textInput.LanguageCode = "en"
       queryInput.Text = textInput

       _Response = _Client.DetectIntent(New SessionName("newagent-12345", _SessionId), queryInput).QueryResult.FulfillmentText

       Debug.Print(_Response)

       Return _Response

   End Function
   ```

where - queryInput contains the text typed by the user.